# Don't see difference between two nginx config

Tags: nginx

guys. I need to your help.
The first config file are working successfully:

```
set $cors "";
if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://auto.*") {
    set $cors "true";
}
if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://dom.*") {
    set $cors "true";
}
location /push/pub/ {
    push_stream_publisher                   admin;
    push_stream_channels_path               $arg_id;
    include allow/servers.*.conf;
    deny all;
}
location ~ /push/sub/(.*) {
    push_stream_subscriber                  long-polling;
    push_stream_channels_path               $1;
    push_stream_last_received_message_tag   $arg_tag;
    push_stream_last_received_message_time  $arg_time;
    push_stream_longpolling_connection_ttl  30s;
}
#cors configuration
    if ($cors = "true") {
      add_header  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'If-Modified-Since';
    }
}
```

I tryed to refactor this code, ang get something like that

```
location /push/pub/ {
    push_stream_publisher                   admin;
    push_stream_channels_path               $arg_id;
    include allow/servers.*.conf;
    deny all;
}

location ~ /push/sub/(.*) {
    push_stream_subscriber                  long-polling;
    push_stream_channels_path               $1;
    push_stream_last_received_message_tag   $arg_tag;
    push_stream_last_received_message_time  $arg_time;
    push_stream_longpolling_connection_ttl  30s;

    if ($http_origin ~* "^https?://(auto|dom).*") {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'If-Modified-Since';
    }
}
```

Now js subscriber listen eternally. Server not response :(
What is the fundamental difference between two configs. I don't understarnd.
Thx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the second case the `if` directive creates another configuration context where you have `add_headers` but don't have `push_stream` configured.

You should learn about how the rewrite module works (it's tricky): http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html
and avoid using `if` as much as possible: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil